# Barcode scanner works only with English layout

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, barcode-scanner

I bought a barcode scanner, but when I use any national keyboard layout (language) I get only letters instead of numbers. In English layout it is working normally (=I get numbers).

Is there any way to make this work under national layouts? Or is there any software which automatically switch layout to English before scanning and back after?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what operating system you are using or what barcade scanner. Or your national keyboard layout, for that matter.

Comment: Windows 7, the reader is this one: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Freeship-Cost-effective-High-Quality-24-Lines-Laser-Desktop-Flatbed-Barcode-Scanner-Bar-code-Reader-with/1451307547.html - I want to use it with Slovak layout.

Comment: I found a little app which changes the lazout based on device, but unfortunately it does not work with Windows 7 www.codeproject.com/Articles/20994/Using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-layouts-on

Answer (score 2):

Most barcode scanners mimic a regular keyboard and send keystrokes, instead of characters, to the host computer. In order to send the proper keystrokes, the scanner must be **configured** to the same keyboard layout as the one being used by the host computer.

An example (find an equivalent for **Numeric transmission** in user's manual of your barcode scanner.)

[image: Numeric transmission]

On *some* products, the keyboard layout is chosen by selecting the appropriate country for keyboard layout (however I don't know if your model accepts such a setting)…